Counting squares in a regular polygon with $4n$ vertices ($n \geq 2$)

Select at random $4$ vertices from a regular polygon with $4n$ vertices ($n \geq 2$). Find $n$ providing that the probability that the $4$ chosen vertices are the vertices of a rectangle that is not a square is $\dfrac{6}{455}$?

Choose $4$ vertices from $4n$ vertices: $\dbinom{4n}{4}$
A regular polygon with $4n$ vertices has $2n$ diameters. Select any two diameters to form a rectangle: $\dbinom{2n}{2}$
The number of squares in a regular polygon with $4n$ vertices is $n.$
So we have $\dfrac{\dbinom{2n}{2} - n}{\dbinom{4n}{4}} = \dfrac{6}{455} \implies n = 4$
My question is about geometry (I believed it's still pretty much combinatorial so I decided to use the combinatorics/probability tag). It wasn't immediate to me that a regular polygon with $4n$ vertices has $n$ squares. I drew a regular octagon and reasoned that for every vertex oriented to be the top, there is a square that 'aligns' with it (illustrated below). However, this square is repeated $3$ times (at the blue vertices in the image). There are $4n$ vertices, so there are $4n/4 = n$ squares. I found this reasoning a bit cumbersome (not to mention it's just a hopeful generalization from a simpler model). I hope to receive some advice.
Thank you!


Your argument is essentially correct, and not particularly cumbersome. The generalization beyond the octahedron is clearer if you start with a vertex of a square rather than with a vertex at "the top".
Each vertex determines a square - step around $n$ steps four times and you return. That square is counted four times, once for each vertex.

Ahhh I see! The orientation you suggested is indeed much clearer to see why the reasoning is correct for larger $n.$ Thank you very much!
